# fetch json to table (endpoint)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fetch

i'm beginner on javascript trying to learn everyday, here i'm trying to fetch json data from url with endpoints, for some reason data is not coming to 'table' i can see it in `console.log` but not on table.
my json data looks like this :

```
{
  "id": "145127236",
  "mygoals": "success",
  "future": "high",
  "dole": {
    "Key": "fhd699f"
  }
}
```

and my code like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-stripped"> 
     <thead>
     <tr> 
         <th> emp id</th>
      <th> emp mygoals</th>
          <th> emp future</th>

     </tr> 
  </thead>
 
 
      <tbody id="data" >
 </tbody>
  </table
</div>


    <script>
  fetch("https://sp*****.com/get/henkilot/98765432/sijoitus",
              {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                 "x-api-key": "p*****w"
              }
            }
          ).then(res =>{ 

        res.json().then(
  data=> {
  console.log(data);
  if(data.length > 0){
  var temp ="";
  
  data.forEach((u) =>{
        temp +="<tr>";
     temp += "<td>"+u.id+"</td>";
     temp += "<td>"+u.mygoals+"</td>";
     temp += "<td>"+u.future+"</td></tr>";

  })
         document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp
  }
  }
   )
    }
  )
 .catch(err => {
          console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a `</tbody>` and `</table` is an unclosed tag

Comment: @Phil  still not working, just in console but not in table

Comment: Please update the code in your question to match any changes

Comment: Also, what is the data you see from `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Phil i see my json which i wrote.

Comment: Ah ok. So your data is not an array so `.length` will be undefined and trying to run `.forEach` on it should result in an error. Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: @Phil its not giving any error

Comment: That would be because `if(data.length > 0)` will never be true so it will never try to execute `.forEach()`

Comment: Remove the `.length` check and the `forEach()` and use `data.id`, `data.mygoals` and `data.future`. Also, fix your HTML table (see first comment)

Comment: Your fetch braces are insane, see my answr

Comment: @Phil sorry for disturbing  answer is already accepted, could you tell me how to make ' <th> emp future</th> ' come under those others, like newline (\n, <br> ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the JSON data that you wrote in the question is not an array, therefore there is no need to iterate over the data. One option is to remove the `forEach` or fix the endpoint response if you have access to it.

This is the code that considers that the endpoint does not respond with an array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-stripped"> 
     <thead>
     <tr> 
         <th> emp id</th>
      <th> emp mygoals</th>
          <th> emp future</th>

     </tr> 
  </thead>
 
 
      <tbody id="data" >
 </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


    <script>
  fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a",
              {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                 "x-api-key": "p*****w"
              }
            }
          ).then(res =>{ 

        res.json().then(
  data=> {
  console.log(data);
  var temp ="";
  
       temp +="<tr>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.id+"</td>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.mygoals+"</td>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.future+"</td></tr>";

     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp
  }
   )
    }
  )
 .catch(err => {
          console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP appears to be getting a response so there doesn't seem to be any CORS issues

Comment: Added an example with the question code, hitting a mock server responding with `[{ "id": "145127236", "mygoals": "success", "future": "high", "dole": { "Key": "fhd699f" } }]`

Comment: @Thiago Romano its not cors issue i'm getting response in console

Comment: Hmm, is the server you are hitting answering with an array (starts with a `[`)?

Comment: But OP's data is **not** an array so why make your example return one? You also haven't fixed the HTML issues

Comment: I have modified the answer to consider that the endpoint does not answer with an array.

Comment: @ThiagoRomano sorry for disturbing your answer is already accepted, could you tell me how to make '  <th> emp future</th>
' come under those others, like newline (\n, <br> ?)

Answer (score 0):

Your braces are insane
try that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-stripped"> 
      <thead>
        <tr> 
          <th> emp id </th>
          <th> emp mygoals </th>
          <th> emp future </th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
      <tbody id="data"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<script>
  const tableData = document.getElementById("data")
    ;
  fetch("https://sp*****.com/get/henkilot/98765432/sijoitus",
    { method: "GET"
    , headers: { "x-api-key": "p*****w" }
    })
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(data=>
    {
    console.log(data)
    data.forEach(u=>
      {
      let newRow = tableData.insertRow()
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = u.id
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = u.mygoals
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = u.future
      })
    })
  .catch(err => console.log("ERROR: " + err) );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```